# Select columns from table by comparing the value with another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables as below

employees (id int, name varchar(20), salary int);

employee_manager(eid int, mid int);

[image]

[image]

I want to get the result as

ID, NAME, Manager_Name

I am able to fetch only the ID for Manager_Name, How can i get the results.

Query to Get name, employee id, manager id(which is employee id)

```
select e.name, e.id, NVL(m.mid, 'NONE') AS Manager_ID
from employees e
left join EMPLOYEE_MANAGER m ON e.id = m.eid;
```

Query to select employee name who is manager.

```
select distinct e.name 
from employees e, EMPLOYEE_MANAGER m
where m.mid = e.id;
```

Comment: eid is the id from employee table, mid is the id from employee table which is employee manager.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: Oracle 12c and running query on sql developer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by left joining on a derived table that joins together `employee_manager` and `employees` to get the manager information:

```
select e.id, e.name, nvl(m.name, 'NONE') as manager_name
  from employees e
  left join (
    select em.eid, m.name
      from employee_manager em
      join employees m
        on m.id = em.mid
  ) m on m.eid = e.id
```